# Where is ro.secure value being stored?

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, android-install-apk

I'm trying to solve problem of installation of APK on AVD.
It seems [here is solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469785/permission-denied-error-while-installing-apk-on-device/7531611#7531611).
But I dont' know how to edit `ro.secure` - where to get it ?
In another answer there `/data/local/tmp` - I don't understand where to get that either.
And I can't ask in comments there, because of lack of rating.

I tried to install APK this way:

```
$ adb install ~/Projects/TestApp/TestApp.apk
/home/andy/Projects/TestApp.... 55.1 MB/s (33084015 bytes in 0.572s)
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/TestApp.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS]
rm failed for -f, Read-only file system
```

With `-r` option it looks like this:

```
Success
rm failed for -f, Read-only file system
```

Comment: How are you installing the app?  AVDs should work out of the box with `adb install YourAppPackageName.apk`

Comment: @Larry Schiefer see above (updated)

Comment: Have you tried `adb install -r ~/Projects/TestApp/TestApp.apk`?

Comment: @stkent the same stuff.

Comment: Possibly helpful? http://www.droidforums.net/threads/editing-default-prop.48098/

Comment: @stkent You know what (how about copy those here): https://www.virustotal.com/#/url/5a7cf8be62f7ec21e97cca9d730ee1d081c5e50e4d97db60ff2823e69d5d0d5f/detection

Comment: The comment @stkent made about using the `-r` option should fix it for you as it tells the system to re-install the app.  If that is failing, it should be giving you a *different* error.

Comment: @Larry Schiefer see end of my question (updated)

Comment: Not sure about that `rm failed...` message.  But, it shows `Success` that the app was (re)installed.

Comment: @Larry Schiefer app doesn't work (unlike on a real device). Yet, how about ro.secure and /data/local/temp ?

Comment: You can't write to the ro.secure properties.  The "ro" stands for read-only.  More importantly, you shouldn't need to modify anything there.